# How can I capitalize selected text in a Google Doc plug-in using the Google Docs API without losing the original text formatting?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

Google App Script: I am trying to build a google doc plug-in that capitalize the selected text on the document, but the capitalization process removes the format of the original text, and I don't want this happen. So what methods I could use from google docs api that will keep the formatting of the text after capitalization.

```
function getSelectedText() {
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const selection = doc.getSelection();
  if (selection) {
    const rangeElements = selection.getRangeElements();
    if (rangeElements.length > 0) {
      const firstElement = rangeElements[0];
      if (firstElement.getElement().editAsText) {
        const startOffset = firstElement.getStartOffset();
        const endOffsetInclusive = firstElement.getEndOffsetInclusive();
        const textElement = firstElement.getElement().editAsText();
        return textElement.getText().substring(startOffset, endOffsetInclusive + 1);
      }
    }
  }
  return '';
}

 function capitalizeText() {
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const selection = doc.getSelection();
  if (selection) {
    const rangeElements = selection.getRangeElements();
    rangeElements.forEach(function(rangeElement) {
       if (rangeElement.getElement().editAsText) {
        const startOffset = rangeElement.getStartOffset();
         const endOffsetInclusive = rangeElement.getEndOffsetInclusive();
        const textElement = rangeElement.getElement().editAsText();
        const selectedText = textElement.getText().substring(startOffset, endOffsetInclusive + 1);
        const capitalizedText = selectedText.toUpperCase();
        textElement.deleteText(startOffset, endOffsetInclusive);
         textElement.insertText(startOffset, capitalizedText);
       }
    });
   } else {
    throw new Error('No text selected.');
  }
}
```

I tried to implement a method that creates a temporary document and copy paste the format then after capitalization is done it retrieves the format to the capitalised text, but this did not work.