# How can I keep the format of the text while replacing it?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am working on building a google docs add-on that calls some specific api and replace the selected text with the response from the api .. However its removing the format of the original text (bold / colors / highlight / etc ...). Is there any way to keep the formatting?

this is the method i am using to replace the selected text.

```
function replaceSelectedTextWithAPI(apiEndpoint) {  try {
  const selectedText = getSelectedText().join("");
  const replacement = callAPIWithSelected(apiEndpoint);
  
  var selection = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();
  if (selection) {
    const elements = selection.getSelectedElements();
    for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
      const element = elements[i].getElement();
      if (element.editAsText) {
        const startIndex = elements[i].getStartOffset();
        const endIndex = elements[i].getEndOffsetInclusive();
        const originalText = element.asText().getText().substring(startIndex, endIndex + 1);
        const escapedOriginalText = escapeRegExp(originalText);
        element.asText().replaceText(escapedOriginalText, replacement);
      }
    }
  }
} catch (error) {
    throw new Error('Error replacing selected text: ' + error.message);
  }
}
```

and this is the method for getting the selected text by the user:

```
function getSelectedText() {
  const selection = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();
  const text = [];
  if (selection) {
    const elements = selection.getSelectedElements();
    for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
      if (elements[i].isPartial()) {
        const element = elements[i].getElement().asText();
        const startIndex = elements[i].getStartOffset();
        const endIndex = elements[i].getEndOffsetInclusive();
        // Logger.log(startIndex)
        // Logger.log(endIndex)

        text.push(element.getText().substring(startIndex, endIndex + 1));
      } else {
        const element = elements[i].getElement();
        if (element.editAsText) {
          const elementText = element.asText().getText();
          if (elementText) {
            text.push(elementText);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if (!text.length) throw new Error('Please select some text.');

  //Logger.log('Selected Text: ' + text); // Output the selected text to the console

  return text;
}
```

I don't know the error, is it form getSelcetedText() method, but this method is from Google themself .. Or it is from the replaceSelectedTextWithAPI() method?

Comment: When I saw this question, I thought that this question was a duplicate of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76308026). But, from `Yes I am not required anymore to solve it.` in your previous question, I understood that you are not required to resolve your previous question. And you want to resolve your new question. So, I reopened this question.

Comment: ok .. can you help me in this question?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `ok .. can you help me in this question?`, yes. I would like to support you. So, when I found a solution, I would like to post it as an answer.

Comment: interface element has a setAttributes() method